# Why does this cause an error in express.js?

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, express

If I include the following snippet of JavaScript in an HTML page served by express.js I get an error. Why?

```
<script>
    var foo = /<%([\s\S]+?)%>/g;            
</script>
```

Error:

```
500 SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL...
```

**Edit:**

Full page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head></head>
<body>
    <script>
        var foo = /<%([\s\S]+?)%>/g;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Node: v0.10.21
NPM: 1.3.11
Express: 3.3.8

**Edit 2:**

If I remove the percentage signs then the error stops. Can I replace the percentage signs with their unicode character encoding?

Comment: The 500 error would be sent from the server, but if you have that in an HTML page, it would be rendered, and an error wouldn't be caught  until the user opens the browser. I'm guessing there's an error somewhere else in the code and this line is catching it.

Comment: What happens when you do `var foo = new RegExp("<%([\s\S]+?)%>", "g");` ?

Comment: @Jason: Same error with your code. I think express is choking on the syntax?

Comment: hmm, but now it's a string so it shouldn't be checking the regex syntax. But I have a bug in that line: You may have to double-escape the `\\`` : `var foo = new RegExp("<%([\\s\\S]+?)%>", "g")`

Comment: Double-escaping has the same issue.

Comment: @Ben aren't you missing single quotes around this? `var foo = '/<%([\s\S]+?)%>/g'`.

Comment: @Ben, Are you minimizing the html? and if so, what does the output look like?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the literal RegExp: `/<%([\s\S]+?)%>/g`. Try adding a type attribute to the tag, i.e. `<script type="text/javascript">...`

Comment: @James - I don't think I am missing quotes - it is a regex and doesn't need them. Nothing is being minimised/altered beyond the code above.

Comment: @ridgerunner - I have tried that to no success.

Comment: @James - Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/F23bC/ That syntax is a legal expression in JS.

Comment: @JaredFarrish yeah it was my mistake.

Comment: If I remove the percentage signs then the error stops. Can I replace the percentage signs with their unicode character encoding?

Comment: Is it possible that the `<%` tags are clashing with some sort of view templating?

Comment: Yes, that sounds possible. I wonder how to circumvent?

Comment: @Ben which view template engine are you using?

Comment: What happens when you use two percent signs to mean one? `var foo = /<%%([\s\S]+?)%%>/g;`

Comment: @James ejs (which has the same syntax as underscore templating (from which this code is)). I believe you are correct it is a clash with ejs. I ill try the double percentages.

Comment: Double percentages does not work. I am hopeful that unicode encoding the percentage in the regex might circumvent the issue.

Comment: It shouldn't hurt JS when you change it to `var foo = /\<\%([\s\S]+?)\%\>/g;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view templating engine (probably EJS) is trying to interpolate part of your regex -- `<%` means "code starts here."

It isn't the most elegant solution, but you could force the template to treat those symbols as a string by interpolating them into the text. Try something like the following:

```
<script>
    var foo = /<%= '<' + '%' %>([\s\S]+?)<%= '%' + '>' %>/g;            
</script>
```

Comment: Is there a way to prevent EJS from parsing a section of the view?

Comment: Asking EJS to spit out `<%` as a string literal should work. `<%= '<' + '%' %>`

Answer (score 1):

I just installed an express server and loaded up EJS to test this. Escaping the percent sign worked when I tried it. I don't know if that will screw up what you are going for though.

```
var foo = /<\%([\s\S]+?)\%>/g;
```